# How can I convince my D&D players to restart their characters?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, player-characters

I'm trying to start a D&D/Pathfinder club and I think that all of the players should restart/re-roll their characters.  Half the group does not want to do so since they are already invested in an existing character from another group, though every one else is new to the game or is open to starting the characters from scratch.

What could I do to convince the people that don't want to restart?

Comment: To clarify: When you say "restart" do you mean you want them to create new characters from scratch?

Comment: Are these players wanting to bring in characters they've developed in _other groups_ unrelated to this club, or have you previously been playing a game with all of them and want to start fresh? This will make a huge difference to the answers you receive.

Comment: What level are the old characters?

Comment: And the obvious question: why?

Comment: Closed because it's unclear and the questioner appears to have bailed.

Answer (score 8):

Some people are attached to their old characters. But obviously, you can't run a campaign where half the players are level 10 and the other half are level 1. If you simply point this out to them, and ask them how they'd feel if the other players were a higher level than them, you should be able to make everyone see that this is necessary.

In the end, though, it's your game. So just ask yourself this: [who's wearing the DM's hat?](http://youtu.be/Df-uemc-e3w?t=43s) And what does that mean for the rules?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to create a golden retire for their old characters.

You can offer them that their characters will have important jobs in the same city/region. Try to work with them interesting destinies.

Maybe, the will appear in the story from time to time, showing how awesome they are. Maybe they even can roleplay them in some occasions. They could be mentors of the new characters, and have missions and advices to the new players.

I think that maybe if they don't just disappear, your players could be more eager to let them go.

Answer (score 3):

Convert characters, rather than replacing them outright. Start by explaining to them that the characters need to all be built under the same system as each other for the game to be able to function as such.

Have them rebuild the same character under the new rules. For most characters this is pretty straightforward (Pathfinder was specifically designed with this in mind), though it will require some homebrewing in the case of mechanics that don't have PF counterparts, such as Incarnum.

If characters are of different levels, you can usually simply start the game at the level of the highest-level character coming in, and give out to everyone else enough xp to raise them to that level (and gold commensurately). Simply write off the advancement as the result of adventures and experiences the characters had off-stage between their last campaign and this one (and encourage them to elaborate on those adventures in backstory).